# Mule SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: connection, mule, reset, socketexception

I have a mule application which exposes a rest webservice.

```
 <inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="${webservice.url}" doc:name="Generic"></inbound-endpoint>
```

I am using jersey resources for rest component.
The code works fine in QA but in UAT it throws the following error.

```
ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy - Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]
        at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readLine(HttpServerConnection.java:245) ~[mule-transport-http-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
        at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.getRequestLine(HttpServerConnection.java:557) ~[mule-transport-http-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
        at org.mule.transport.http.HttpRequestDispatcherWork.run(HttpRequestDispatcherWork.java:67) ~[mule-transport-http-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

Telnet to the port is working. cron jobs are working fine in the server except the rest methods.

Comment: What is the Mule version? Is the endpoint an HTTP inbound? Is there a reason not to use the HTTP Listener? Is it HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: its mule 3.8.1, Yes it is http inbound. I tried modifying the code to http listener. It didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Connection request means that the other side closed the connection. Given that the application works in one environment I assume that the problem is the environment. You have to find out what is different between the environments to cause that problem. Is there anything between the client and the Mule application? A load balancer, proxy, etc? Difference in timeouts? Performing a network traffic capture from both sides could be helpful to isolate the problem.